# In Rails, Multiple sources of input (to create), Conditional return of the input view with errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have an application with two means of inputting data: (1) a single-entry page / a `form_with` fields [ aka 'input_page' ] and (2) a file upload page  [ aka 'file_upload_page' ] that accepts a spreadsheet with multiple entries (here, student courses).

My goal is to have the validation error messages appear on the view associated with the source of input, either the input_page or the file_upload_page.

The courses controller currently looks like this:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @course = (Course.import(params[:course][:file]) || 
    Course.new(course_params))
    # the input is either a file (spreadsheet) or the aforementioned 
    # `form_with` fields 
  @course.save

respond_to do |format|
  if @course.save
    # when successful, both inputs return the same view,
    #  `courses_path` 

    format.html { redirect_to courses_path, notice: '...success!' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: 
      courses_path }

  else
    # here is where the 'challenge' arises for the single input_page

    format.html { redirect_to input_page, alert: 
      course.errors.full_messages }

    # now, how do I *conditionally* return the file_upload_page if
    # the user uploaded multiple courses with a spreadsheet

    format.html { redirect_to file_upload_page, alert: 
      course.errors.full_messages }
  end
```

(The uploaded spreadsheet file is parsed using the Roo gem in the courses model, courses are saved, and returned to the courses controller, create action.)

Currently, (1) a successful save of either the input_page or the file_upload_page - correctly - returns the courses_path.  (2) If validations fail, both the input_page and the file_upload_page return the input_page view - because that code is run first.

I need something in the `else` block like 'if input is from X view, return X view with errors, else return Z view with errors'

Comment: You should use proper ruby comments instead of this confusing notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your params tell you if it's a file upload or not so use that logic to determine the errors path:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @course = Course.import(params[:course][:file]) || Course.new(course_params)
  if @course.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to courses_path, notice: '...success!' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: courses_path }
    end
  else
    errors_path = params[:course][:file] ? file_upload_page : input_page
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to errors_path, alert: course.errors.full_messages }
      end
  end
end
```

Comment: I edited and accepted your answer.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: in proposed your edit, where is `@cpe_event` defined? There's no way I would have known that from your question.

Comment: Sorry, I was working on another project and tested the code there.  Without `format.html { ... }`, I get this error: `ActionController::UnknownFormat - ActionController::UnknownFormat:`